# Configuração do envio de e-mail no Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, envio-de-email, configuração

Preciso implementar uma tela de configuração, onde o usuário poderá setar os dados para o envio de e-mail como: `MAIL_DRIVER`, `MAIL_HOST`, `MAIL_PORT`, 
`MAIL_USERNAME`, `MAIL_PASSWORD`, `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`, etc.
Neste caso o sistema não vai obter estas informações do arquivo de configuração do Laravel, mas sim, da base de dados.

Alguém conhece uma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte:

Entre no site https://mailtrap.io/ e crie uma conta.
Após isso, abra o arquivo **.env** e defina as seguintes configurações:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=nome de usuario gerado no mailtrap
MAIL_PASSWORD=senha gerada no mailtrap
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Nome de Envio"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@deenvio.com.br
```

Em seguida, no arquivo **routes/web.php** adicione:

```
Route::get('pagina/enviar-email/{id}', 'NomeDoController@sendMail')->name('nome.da.rota.aqui');
```

Após isso, abra seu terminal e digite o comando **php artisan make:mail EnviarEmail** .
Será criado o arquivo EnviarEmail na pasta nomeada como **Mai**l em **App/Http**.

Após isso, deixe o arquivo exatamente como o código abaixo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EnviarMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
        * Armazena os campos que serão enviados.
        *
        * @access protected
        * @property array $inputs
        */
    protected $inputs;

    /**
        * Cria uma nova instância e
        * armazena os valores dos campos
        * a serem enviados.
        *
        * @access public
        * @param array $inputs
        * @return void
        */
    public function __construct(array $inputs)
    {
        $this->inputs = $inputs;
    }

    /**
        * Constrói o e-mail a ser enviado.
        * 
        * @access public 
        * @param void
        * @uses view()
        * @return $this
        */
    public function build()
    {
        /**
        * Utiliza uma view qualquer definida, 
        * e atribui a ela os valores 
        * a serem enviados por email.
        *
        **/
        return $this->view('caminho.da.view.aqui')
        ->with(['campo' => $this->inputs]);
```

}
}

Construa a **view** que será utilizada para enviar o e-mail junto aos campos:

```
<h1>E-mail de Contato</h1>
<p>Apenas um E-mail</p>

<ul>
    <li>Nome: {{ $campo->nome }}</li>
    <li>E-mail: {{ $campo->email }}</li>
    <li>Login: {{ $campo->valor1 }}</li>
    <li>Senha: {{ $campo->valor2 }}</li>
</ul>
```

No **Controller**, adicione este metodo:

```
/**
* Executa envio de e-mail.
*
* @access public 
* @param int $id
* @uses Mail::to()
* @uses Session:flash()
* @throws Exception
* @return Route
**/
public function sendMail(int $id)
{
    /**
    * Mail pode gerar uma exceção, devido a isso
    * executamos o envio com intuito de capturá-la
    * e posteriormente tratá-la.
    **/
    try{
        Mail::to('email@dominio.com.br')->send( new EnviarEmail( NomeDoModel::find($id) ) ) ;
        // Mostra uma mensagem de sucesso se enviado
        Session::flash('success', 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!');
    }catch(Exception $e){
        // Mostra uma mensagem de falha senão enviado
        Session::flash('fail', 'Não foi possível enviar o e-mail!');
    }

    // Redireciona após envio ou falha.
    return redirect()->route('nome.da.rota.aqui', $id);
}
```

Caso funcione ou não, dê um feedback.

Observação: As configurações do mailtrap podem ser substituidas pela que você desejar. Utilizei o mailtrap apenas com a finalidade de testar.